# Make sure http post comes from my applet and no one else?

Tags: java, php, mysql, applet

I have an applet that communicates with php through http post requests and then my php script inserts data in a mysql database. So the problem is that i guess anyone can make a http post requests and add data to my mysql database if they now the "post" names and of course i dont want that.

So i would like to have som solution where my php can be sure that the http requests are really from my applet and no one else. I would be grateful for ideas on how to solve this. The data being sent contains no secrets so it dont need to be encrypted if it can be solved with no encryption that is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use encryption while communicating , so the answer is simply you can't make sure.

Comment: agreed - if you are not encrypting the "security" mechanism, then it is likely relatively easy to "sniff" the communication and spoof it.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, even *with* encryption, it is impossible to determine whether a request was made by your applet or by something else that is perfectly mimicing its behavior. You will need to build your application such that it can deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

Encryption will help secure any methodology you will put into place in order to achieve what you want, but it will do nothing on its own.

What you want is to *authenticate* the post message. This is usually achieved by having your client (here, applet) sign ([HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code)) the POST message using a key that only the applet AND the server knows. The challenge here is that you need to securely store the key on the client side.

If I were you I would check into authenticating the users and hosting the applet in a secured area of your site, making sure your applet is re-using the HTTP session of the authenticated user when performing POST requests. Add to this basic safeguards against standard attacks (ie Cross Site Request Forgery, Replay attack, etc). This setup would make sure your requests come from your site by authorized users.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the applet register by generating an RSA key pair on the client and sending the public key to the server. The server then keeps track of the public key of each registered client.

On each POST the client signs some piece of data using the private key, and includes the signature and the public key (or a hash of the public key) to identify itself. The server verifies that the public key is registered, and verifies the signature.

There would be no way to mimic this short of stealing the private key from the client, or breaking RSA encryption. Well, I guess you could record and replay somebody else's POST. There is that problem to solve.

However, you could have a fake client follow the steps of registration and send a public key, and then that fake client would be free to POST along with all valid clients. So there is that problem to solve, too.